# How does get('order') work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm leaning JavaScript and Backbone.js. Now I'm reading the [Todo application example in Backbone.js](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/) by Addy Osmani, and confused with the following segment:

```
// We keep the Todos in sequential order, despite being saved by unordered
// GUID in the database. This generates the next order number for new items.
nextOrder: function() {
    if ( !this.length ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return this.last().get('order') + 1;
},

// Todos are sorted by their original insertion order.
comparator: function( todo ) {
    return todo.get('order');
}
```

In fact I didn't find any `'order'` attribute anywhere else, could anyone point out how the `get('order')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out where nextOrder is called:

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      title: "empty todo...",
      order: Todos.nextOrder(),
      done: false
    };
  },
```

We are setting the order of the model here. If there aren't any existing orders it's set to 1. If there are any -- the last order has the highest index thus far.

Comment: Thank you. Finally find it in app.js, it's added to the todo item when the item is created. A little confused why not declare it in the model?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [source for `get`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-35) will be instructive:

```
get: function(attr) {
  return this.attributes[attr];
}
```

So when you say `m.get('a')`, Backbone will look for `'a'` inside `m.attributes`. The big lesson here is that Backbone model attributes and JavaScript object properties aren't the same thing: you access attribute `a` using `m.get('a')` whereas property `p` is accessed via `m.p`. There are various reasons for separating attributes and properties, a couple of the main ones would be:

1. You don't want your model attributes to have naming conflicts with properties and methods.
2. You want to know which parts of a model should be persisted to the server and sent to templates for rendering (see [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) and in the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-33)).

Another lesson is that the Backbone source is actually pretty readable and fairly easy to understand once you have a basic knowledge of JavaScript. The [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) is handy when you don't know your way around the Backbone internals.